# url rewrite to hide querystring and php file extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently, my page is:

```
http://example.com/profile/customer.php?page=2
```

I want to rewrite url as:

```
http://example.com/profile/customer
```

My existing .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But this code hides only file extension and not the query string.

Comment: Are you sure this is what your want ? What about other page argument ?

Comment: The rewrite should expand '..../customer' to '..../customer.php?page=2'?

Comment: my requirement is this. for other pages also i need the same.

Comment: It's not possible for a variable query. Although you can hardcode /customer.php?page=2 to /customer, which means /customer.php?page=3 or anything else won't work. Although you can try transmitting data in the `$_POST` method and that should work instead of getting data in the `$_GET` method. But you can rewrite the URL to /customer/X where X = ?page=X

Comment: It is better to have `http://example.com/profile/customer/2` and `http://example.com/profile/customer/3` kind of URLs.